# angular 15 util.js Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: angular, npm, twilio, twilio-api, polyfills

I am trying to integrate **Voice JavaScript SDK** into an Angular 15 application. After installing the required `npm` packages, if I run the app I am getting the below error in browser console and UI is not getting displayed.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at 74 (util.js:109:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 3971 (checks.js:6:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 8096 (index.js:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 3421 (backoff.js:5:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 5307 (index.js:4:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
```

I checked how to address this issue and I found that i have to add the below code to `polyfills.ts`

```
import * as process from 'process';
window['process'] = process;
```

It turns out Angular is no longer supporting `polyfills.ts` file. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem. If I learn anything, I'll let you know,.

Answer (score 1):

1. npm install process
2. create file "src/process.ts" and put above code in it
3. in tsconfig.app.json add "src/process.ts" in files section
4. in angular.json add "src/process.ts" in polyfills section